# What caused rotation in exported blender model to jMonkey? (OGRE)

Tags: java, blender, jmonkeyengine

First off, I am very new to jMonkeyEngine 3 and still learning. Not exactly sure what could be causing my snowman to have already been rotated before import. I created him in blender and it was facing forward. The up axis was Z and the forward axis was Y.

For some reason when it is imported into jMonkey I got it pre-rotated which is not what I wanted nor what I coded. I just imported like this tutorial says to do in the book.

Exported as ORGE > Converted to .j3o > Imported with code.

```
snowMan = assetManager.loadModel("Models/Snowman/snowman.j3o");
Material matVC = new Material(assetManager, "Common/MatDefs/Misc/Unshaded.j3md");
matVC.setBoolean("VertexColor", true);
snowMan.setMaterial(matVC);
rootNode.attachChild(snowMan);
```

**What should I look at doing to try and remedy this? Not even sure where to start. Could it be messed up in blender? The way I exported? jMonkey?**

**Update #1:** *I think it has to do with either the exporter or something I did in blender... not sure what though. Pretty sure it is not the fault of jMonkey.*

Now it looks like this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is the the OGRE exporter and will be contacted soon about issue.

Recommend to use .obj with UV Mapping instead since it does not support vertex coloring.

Answer (score 0):

That's a [left vs right hand coordinate system](http://www.evl.uic.edu/ralph/508S98/coordinates.html). It's actually not a rotation but a reflection. It seems that blender uses a right hand coordinate system and jMonkeyEngine or Ogre use left hand coordinate system. If you want to convert between the two system check this [detailed paper](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/LeftHandedToRightHanded.pdf), with the simplest solution being to flip the actual Z direction.

Also here is a related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263072/changing-a-matrix-from-right-handed-to-left-handed-coordinate-system).

Comment: Ok, so I see the Quaternion math... how would you go about this in jMonkey? Would you just rotate the rootNode, or each object? I tried flipping it myself before asking... still has a small tilt like in the pictures.

Comment: @gemurdock I think you only need to flip the final matrix when you export the file.

Comment: Since Ogre exporter doesn't support this how would you go about this?

Comment: I just finished trying this with a new Cube... It did rotate it weird, so I think your right, but it was rotate in more of a 45, 90, 180 degree kind of thing... not this off by 15 to 20 degree... so I think there is still something else at play as well. Maybe something I messed up in blender like the origin. Still not used to blender yet.

Comment: While the Axis are switched around, everyone in my reading keeps saying both are right handed coordinate systems. http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/forum/topic/questions-on-coordinate-system-etc/ and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/471/is-it-possible-to-make-blender-a-y-up-world - So not exactly sure what to think now. Waiting for you to have a chance to get back to me.

Comment: @gemurdock you can check if a system is right handedness or left handedness by calculating the matrix determinant negative determinant is left handed.

Comment: @gemurdock you also need to make sure how the matrices are encoded OGre for instance has a row matrix.

Comment: Ok, well all 3 (OpenGL included) are right handed. Ok, it is in XML and has a row matrix. I would have to write a program to go through the XML and switch it, so I see what your saying. However, since all three are right handed... then this wouldn't help in my situation would it? - Also, the book doesn't mention anything like this and directly suggests to use blender for jMonkey... even goes as far as to tell you how to make a model and import it, which I followed. I think the image may have been deceiving.

Comment: @gemurdock then you need to make sure that all the row and column matrices are compatible, I can't follow anymore TBH because I don't use ogre or jmonkey or blender.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I just had this same problem and got it fixed, so..

Select your snowman in blender and press alt+R to clear rotation. Now it's probably going to look the same as in jMonkey. Apparently the ogre exporter doesn't apply rotations you made to the object.

To fix this, apply the rotation permanently to the snowman in blender: from the object menu -> apply -> rotation. Now it should load fine in jMonkey.